# How to simplify boolean expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

Can someone show me step by step how to simplify this boolean expression? I would like to learn how to handle this kind of simplifications:

$$
Y = \neg(D \wedge\neg E) \vee (\neg E \wedge D )
$$

I can apply boolean laws for the first steps, that should be:

1. De Morgan's law : $\neg D \vee \neg\neg E \vee (\neg E \wedge D)$
2. Elimination of double negation : $\neg D \vee E \vee (\neg E \wedge D)$

From here i don't know what to do. Except that final result is $\top$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distribute the result with the distribution law $A \vee ( B \wedge C ) = (A \vee B) \wedge (A \vee C )$.  Letting $A = (\neg D \vee E)$, $B = \neg E$ and $C = D$ you obtain
$$
(\neg D \vee E) \vee (\neg E \wedge D) = ((\neg D \vee E) \vee \neg E ) \wedge ((\neg D \vee E) \vee D ).
$$

Obviously, $E \vee \neg E = \top$ and likewise for $D$.  Besides $\top \vee A = \top$ for a term $A$.  Therefore the expression reduces as follows.

$$
(\neg D \vee E \vee \neg E ) \wedge (\neg D \vee E \vee D ) = (\neg D \vee \top ) \wedge (\top \vee E ) = \top \wedge \top = \top
$$

But you don't really need all that trouble.  If you let $X = \neg E \wedge D$, your expression became $Y = \neg X \vee X$, which again equals $\top$.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand your first step. You say distribute, but i don't see which are terms of the distributive law. Can you explain please? Ok for the second method.

Comment: Done.  I had hoped bracketing a lot would be clear enough.

Comment: Really thanks, now it's clear.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\color{green}{\neg (\neg D \vee E)} = \color{red}{D \wedge \neg E}$$

From the question (part 2) we have 
$$Y=\neg D \vee E \vee \color{red}{(\neg E \wedge D)}$$
substituting the above term in the $Y$ expression we get
$$ Y= (\neg D \vee E ) \vee \color{green}{\neg (\neg D \vee E )} = A \vee \neg A = \top $$

Comment: Rigth, seems a good solution, i appreciate that.